# how to turn this blockchain script in a one liner?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, minify, blockchain

I know how to use this blockchain script on the server, but I don't know how to [minify](https://javascript-minifier.com/minify) it into a single function (only one return), best would be one liner:

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
    if(this.length ==0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return parseInt(this.split('').map(function(char){
            return char.charCodeAt(0);
        }).reduce(function(current, previous){
            return previous + current;
        }))+ (this.substr(1, this.length)).hashCode();
    }
};
nonce = 0;
while(true){
    hash = (transaction + nonce).hashCode() % 1234;
    if (hash ==0){
        break;
    }
    nonce++;
}
return nonce;
```

Of course, transaction is a string.
I tried to replace this with hash, but since hashcode function calls itself, I don't know how to manage this loop without function.

Your result must work in the minify link above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct translation of the original code

```
function findNonce( data ){
var buffer, i, hash, nonce = -1;
    data = '' + ( data || '' );
    do {
        hash = 0;
        nonce++;
        buffer = data + nonce;
        i = buffer.length;
        while(i--) hash += buffer.charCodeAt(i) * (i+1);
    } while ( hash % 1234 );
    return nonce;
};
```

And, once minified,

```
function findNonce(n){var e,o,r,t=-1;n=""+(n||"");do for(r=0,t++,e=n+t,o=e.length;o--;)r+=e.charCodeAt(o)*(o+1);while(r%1234);return t}
```

But if better performance is required this should be optimized, calculating first the hash for the input string and then doing only the calcs for each nonce value.

```
function findNonceFast( data ){
var preHash, noncePos, nonce = -1, code; 
    function hashCalc( s, hash, pos ){
        var i = s.length; while(i--) hash += s.charCodeAt(i) * (i+pos+1);
        return hash;
    };
    data =  '' + ( data || '' );
    preHash = hashCalc( data, 0, 0 );
    noncePos = data.length;
    do {
        nonce++;
        code = hashCalc( ''+nonce, preHash, noncePos );
    } while (code % 1234)
    return nonce;
};
```

Minified

```
function findNonceFast(n){function r(n,r,t){for(var e=n.length;e--;)r+=n.charCodeAt(e)*(e+t+1);return r}var t,e,o,a=-1;n=""+(n||""),t=r(n,0,0),e=n.length;do a++,o=r(""+a,t,e);while(o%1234);return a}
```

Comment: Fast reply, optimized and hints to build the other function. You're a true helpful JS guru. I'd love to work with people like you. Selected as reply.